# using toggle to optimise a working jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and have this badly written code that works. However i want to optimise it. Code as it stands is like this

```
 jQ('#Thur1More_SplitDayButton').click(function(){           
            if(jQ(this).attr('value')=='Un Split'){
                jQ(this).val('Split Day'); 
                jQ('#Thur1_Split').slideUp("fast");
                jQ('.Thur1').val("");
            }else{
                jQ(this).val('Un Split'); 
                jQ('#Thur1_Split').slideDown("fast");
            }
})
jQ('#Fri1More_SplitDayButton').click(function(){
            if(jQ(this).attr('value')=='Un Split'){
                jQ(this).val('Split Day'); 
                jQ('#Fri1_Split').hide();
                jQ('.Fri1').val("");
            }else{
                jQ(this).val('Un Split'); 
                jQ('#Fri1_Split').show();
            }
})
```

and so on for the 10 buttons that control the slide up and slide down of the adjacent div.

To optimise i have given all the buttons a class of SplitDayButton and the Divs all have a class of timesheet2. I have tried the following code to no avail

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $('.SplitDayButton').toggle(
              function() {
         $(this).closest('.timesheet2').slideUp("fast");
             }, function() {
          $(this).closest('.timesheet2').slideDown("fast");
     })
   })
```

I am using closest to find the div adjacent the button that needs the action applied to. The html structure is similar to this

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="timesheet1">...content</div>
      <div class="timesheet2">...content</div>
      <div class="timesheet3">
      <div class="button1" id="SplitButton1">
            <input name="mybutton1" id="mybutton1" type="button" value="Split Day" class="btn SplitDayButton">
      </div>
    </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="timesheet1">...content</div>
  <div class="timesheet2">...content</div>
  <div class="timesheet3">
    <div class="button2" id="SplitButton2">
            <input name="mybutton2" id="mybutton2" type="button" value="Split Day"   class="btn SplitDayButton">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I have created a fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/g4eucpL5/11/

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your fiddle is trying to illustrate. My answer below will help you with the "10 buttons" so that you don't have to duplicate your JS code 10X.

Comment: I updated my code. There was bug that made was making the both elements slide toggle if you clicked on the first button.

Answer (score 0):

For code like your first JS example, try using parameters to map them into shared functions.

```
$('#Thur1More_SplitDayButton').click(function(){  
  a($(this), '#Thur1_Split', '.Thur1', 'Un Split');
});

$('#Fri1More_SplitDayButton').click(function(){
  var obj = $(this);
  b(obj, '#Fri1_Split', '.Fri1', 'Un Split');
});
```

These can be used by both of your jQuery selectors.

```
function a(obj, id, className, matchStr) {
  if (obj.attr('value') === matchStr) {
    obj.val('Split Day'); 
    $(id).slideUp("fast");
    $(className).val("");
  } else {
    obj.val(matchStr); 
    $(id).slideDown("fast");
  }
}

function b(obj, id, className, matchStr) {
    if (obj.attr('value') === matchStr) {
        obj.val('Split Day'); 
        $(id).hide();
        $(className).val("");
    } else {
        obj.val(matchStr); 
        $(id).show();
    }
}
```

Now noticing the similarities above, you can combine functions into 1.

```
function c(key, obj, id, className, matchStr) {
    if (obj.attr('value') === matchStr) {
        obj.val('Split Day');
        if (key === 'a') {
          $(id).slideUp("fast");
        } else { // b
          $(id).hide();
        }
        $(className).val("");
    } else {
        obj.val(matchStr); 
        if (key === 'a') {
          $(id).slideDown("fast");
        } else { // b
          $(id).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then go back & change your function names + add a key into your jQuery click listeners.

```
$('#Thur1More_SplitDayButton').click(function(){  
  c('a', $(this), '#Thur1_Split', '.Thur1', 'Un Split');
});

$('#Fri1More_SplitDayButton').click(function(){
  var obj = $(this);
  c('b', obj, '#Fri1_Split', '.Fri1', 'Un Split');
});
```

Comment: afaik `obj.attr('value')` can be replaced by `obj.val()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to slide the elements with a certain class name up or down you can use the following JQuery.

**Update:** I wanted to let you know that your jsfiddle is throwing the following error which would cause problems no matter what code you are using. **Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3.** In the fiddle link posted below I removed the bootstrap JavaScript file resource.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/g4eucpL5/92/)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.SplitDayButton').on("click",function(){

      //get the index of the button element
      var index = $(".SplitDayButton").index(this);  

     //select the timesheet2 class element
     var elem = $(".timesheet2")[index];        

     //slide the element up or down
     $(elem).slideToggle("fast");          

    });
});
```